# Installed NLog but NLog.config file is locked in my .netcore xUnit Test Project

Tags: logging, .net-core, nlog, xunit

I have VS2019 and created a xUnit Test Project with .Net Core 3.1.

I installed the Nlog and other things as below through Nuget.

```
<PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.7.12" />
<PackageReference Include="NLog.Config" Version="4.7.12" />
<PackageReference Include="NLog.Schema" Version="4.7.12" />
```

The NLog.config file is locked and unable to edit. What's the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the locked NLog.config file.
Then added the file manually as suggested in https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.config

And set the '*Copy to Output Directory*' as '*Copy if newer*' for that file.

Added the below settings to log to the console

In Targets:

```
<target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />
```

In Rules:

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
```

Then it woked fine.